# Azure error: 'One or more ports used by the Compute Emulator are currently used by other processes'

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting my feet wet with Windows Azure and created a brand new ASP.Net Web Role project in VS.Net 2013. When I start the debugger I get the error: 'One or more ports used by the Compute Emulator are currently used by other processes'.

Both the Compute and Storage emulators start up fine, and don't exit with an error. It's only Visual Studio that throws this error.

I've used the netstat -an command as well as the TCPView utility from SysInternals to try to identify another application using any of the ports used by the Compute Emulator, but nothing else is using those ports! TCPView allows sorting ports in ABC order and I've gone through each port one by one.

Also tried reinstalling the entire Azure suite of tools + multiple reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution was to comment out all references to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink in both the 64 bit and 32 bit machine.config files. For some reason that assembly could not be loaded. The actual error message displayed was about ports in use, but that turned out to be totally unrelated to the root cause.

I spent a few days working this out, so hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, amazingly, what resolved it for me was running Visual Studio as Administrator. Putting this here in case any other poor soul encounters the same.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the "one or more ports used by Computer emulator ..." error happened after a dialog box showed an exception for "DevFc.exe" stopped working.

DevFC logs in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\dftmp\DevFCLogs had below exception log:

```
error (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions) occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=127.0.0.1:15100.
```

So there was problem with 15100 port.

I have to change the port in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Emulator\devfabric\DevFC.exe.config" for PxeResponderPort from 15100 to some other random port, 15200 in my case.

`<add key="PxeResponderPort" value="15200" />`